# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.24/$injector/modulerr?p0=curveApp&p1=Error%…rjs.org%2F1.2.24%2F%24injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3DngRoute%26p1%3DError%253A...<omitted>...0)
```

Im getting the above error in my Laravel/Angular application.  I went to the URL and I'm still not sure what the error is coming from.

I have a file `app.js` in `project/public/js` with this code:

```
var curveApp = angular.module('curveApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'curveControllers'
]);
```

And then a file `config.js` in `project/public/js` with this code:

```
curveApp.config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/register', {
                templateUrl: 'partials/register.html',
                controller: 'RegisterCtrl'
            });
    }
]);
```

Sorry for the beginner questions -- I'd google to find answers but I'm not quite sure what to be looking for.

I'm trying to create HTML templates in project/public/js/partials and have them switch based on the URI without the page refreshing.

Comment: The ngRoute module is defined in angular-route.js. Is there a reference to this file in a script tag?

Answer (score 0):

This errors show that, when some of your modules doesn't exist in page and not included, make sure what `ngRoute` and `curveControllers` are defined and attached to your DOM.

Comment: Sorrry, i'm new to Angular.  How do I do this?